# How do i get div-height?

Tags: javascript, height

How do I calculate `div2.offsetHeight` within `for` loop after each added child before the append of the whole div?

```
var children = store.children;
for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
  var child = children[i];
  div1.innerHTML += child.outerHTML;
}
div2.appendChild(div1);
console.log(div2.offsetHeight);
```

Comment: You said u want div2 height in for loop, it will always be 0 since it is empty inside for loop. Do you mean div1 offset height inside for loop ?

Comment: Exactly. No, div2 is an accumulation of div1. Div1 is an accumulation divs also next to each. Perhaps I need a workaround/solution of multiple for loops or adding and later removing a child within for loop.

Comment: Well sorry but neither ur question nor ur comment explains what u really want